# Get file/directory size using Java 7 new IO

Tags: nio, java-7

How can I get the size of a file or directory using the new NIO in java 7?

Comment: What's wrong with the old way? Unless there is support for recursive directory size now. Is there?

Comment: i've heard it is a lot faster. and i want to try that.

Comment: I have to wonder how it can be faster..

Comment: i think its because the check if a java.io.File is a directory or not is very slow.

Comment: @clamp: and **why** do you think that that's the case?

Comment: for example here: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6483858 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354703/is-there-a-workaround-for-javas-poor-performance-on-walking-huge-directories

Comment: @clamp: at least the second item can *indeed* be solved by using `Path`: since it returns an `Iterator`, it doesn't need to have resolved all members of the directory at the time the `iterator()` call returns and thus can "stream" the directory content, which more closely aligns with the native APIs on most OSes.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use [`Files.size(Path)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to get the size of a file.

For the size of a directory (meaning the size of all files contained in it), you still need to recurse manually, as far as I know.

Comment: I think above method is not present in Java7 I/O, Please check once

Comment: @Damodar: my answer contains a link to the JavaDoc. Why do you think that it's not present?

Comment: He linked to Oracle's official API docs. The method is there.

Comment: thanks, then my next question would be, how would i recurse into a path's childpaths?

Comment: @clamp: a `Path` *is* an `Iterable<Path>`, so you can just do `for (Path child : parent) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a ready to run example that will also skip-and-log directories it can't enter. It uses [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) to accumulate state.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("c:/");
    long size = getSize(path);
    System.out.println("size=" + size);
}

static long getSize(Path startPath) throws IOException {
    final AtomicLong size = new AtomicLong(0);

    Files.walkFileTree(startPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file,
                BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            size.addAndGet(attrs.size());
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc)
                throws IOException {
            // Skip folders that can't be traversed
            System.out.println("skipped: " + file + "e=" + exc);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });

    return size.get();
}
```

Comment: Wondering why the `AtomicLong` is necessary?  Why not just a `long` ?  Is there something parallel about [walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) ?

Comment: tbh, i just rewrote the other answer without using 3pp (MutableLong). But I think the variable has to be "final" to be accessed from the inner anonymous class. Which AtomicLong allows.

Comment: The method `postVisitDirectory`may be also overriden. It's not required to mark the `size` reference as final here because it isn't changed in the inner anonymous class. Only its content (value) is changed. A long array (with one single element) can be used in place of AtomicLong.

Answer (score 5):

```
MutableLong size = new MutableLong();
Files.walkFileTree(directoryPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                size.add(attrs.size());
            }
}
```

This would calculate the size of all files in a directory. However, note that all files in the directory need to be regular files, as API specifies size method of BasicFileAttributes:

*"The size of files that are not regular files is implementation specific and therefore unspecified."*

If you stumble to unregulated file, you ll have either to not include it size, or return some unknown size. You can check if file is regular with

```
BasicFileAttributes.isRegularFile()
```

Comment: Nice answer, and for anyone wondering the Mutable* classes for primitives are part of apache.commons.lang