# Files.walk(), calculate total size

Tags: java, nio, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to calculate the size of the files on my disc. In java-7 this could be done using [Files.walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) as shown in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255592/get-file-directory-size-using-java-7-new-io/19869323#comment32024328_19869323).

However if i wanted to do this using java-8 streams it will work for some folders, but not for all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    long size = Files.walk(Paths.get("c:/")).mapToLong(MyMain::count).sum();
    System.out.println("size=" + size);
}

static long count(Path path) {
    try {
        return Files.size(path);
    } catch (IOException | UncheckedIOException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Above code will work well for path `a:/files/` but for `c:/` it will throw below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: c:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-20
at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.LongPipeline.reduce(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.LongPipeline.sum(Unknown Source)
at MyMain.main(MyMain.java:16)
```

I understand where it is coming from and how to avoid it using Files.walkFileTree API.

But how can this exception be avoided using [Files.walk()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) API?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, this exception cannot be avoided.

The exception itself occurs inside the the lazy fetch of `Files.walk()`, hence why you are not seeing it early and why there is no way to circumvent it, consider the following code:

```
long size = Files.walk(Paths.get("C://"))
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .mapToLong(this::count)
        .sum();
```

On my system this will print on my computer:

```
C:\
C:\$Recycle.Bin
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18
```

And as an exception is thrown on the (main) thread on the third file, all further executions on that thread stop.

I believe this is a design failure, because as it stands now `Files.walk` is absolutely unusable, because you never can guarantee that there will be no errors when walking over a directory.

One important point to notice is that the stacktrace includes a `sum()` and `reduce()` operation, this is because the path is being lazily loaded, so at the point of `reduce()`, the bulk of stream machinery gets called (visible in stacktrace), and then it fetches the path, at which point the `UnCheckedIOException` occurs.

It could *possibly* be circumvented if you let every walking operation execute on their own thread. But that is not something you would want to be doing anyway.

Also, checking if a file is actually accessible is *worthless* (though useful to some extent), because you can not guarantee that it is readable even 1ms later.

#### Future extension

I believe it can still be fixed, though I do not know how `FileVisitOption`s exactly work.
Currently there is a `FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS`, if it operates on a per file basis, then I would suspect that a `FileVisitOption.IGNORE_ON_IOEXCEPTION` could also be added, however we cannot correctly inject that functionality in there.

Comment: Yes, agreed. This is a design failure.

Comment: Good analyzis. I think i would prefer maybe another Files.walk() that also accepted an errorHandler or similiar.

Comment: Yes, good analysis, +1. The bug (enhancement request) that covers this is [JDK-8039910](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039910).

Comment: 6 years later, the bug's closed with resolution "Future Project" and there's no signs of the latter :(

Answer (score 22):

2017 for those who keep arriving here.

**Use Files.walk() when** you are certain of the file system behaviour and really want to stop when there is any error. Generally Files.walk is not useful in standalone apps. I make this mistake so often, perhaps I am lazy. I realize my mistake the moment I see the time taken lasting more than a few seconds for something small like 1 million files.

I recommend `walkFileTree`. Start by implementing the FileVisitor interface, here I only want to count files. Bad class name, I know.

```
class Recurse implements FileVisitor<Path>{

    private long filesCount;
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        //This is where I need my logic
        filesCount++;
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
        // This is important to note. Test this behaviour
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
       return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    public long getFilesCount() {
        return filesCount;
    }
}
```

Then use your defined Class like this.

```
Recurse r = new Recurse();
Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("G:"), r);
System.out.println("Total files: " + r.getFilesCount());
```

I am sure you know how to modify your own class'es implementation of the `FileVisitor<Path>` Interface class to do other things like `filesize` with the example I posted. Refer to the docs for other methods in this

Speed:

- Files.walk : 20+ minutes and failing with exception
- Files.walkFileTree: 5.6 seconds, done with perfect answer.

Edit:
As with everything, use tests to confirm the behaviour
Handle Exceptions, they do still occur except for the ones we choose not to care about as above.

Comment: Apache Commons-IO's DirectoryWalker is about as fast Files.walkFileTree. https://docs.leponceau.org/java-examples/java-evaluation/org.apache.commons.io.FileWalkerPerfTest.html vs https://docs.leponceau.org/java-examples/java-evaluation/tests.java.nio.file.FilesWalkFileTreePerfTest.html

Comment: It's best to extend `SimpleFileVisitor` (abstract class) instead of `FileVisitor` (interface). However you have to override `visitFileFailed()` because the default implementation ironically mimics `Files.walk()`.

Comment: yeah people will insist on using Files.walk() and hit the same problem. It isnt a bug per se but interface exists for these reasons. This is the way

Answer (score 5):

I found that using Guava's Files class solved the issue for me:

```
    Iterable<File> files = Files.fileTreeTraverser().breadthFirstTraversal(dir);
    long size = toStream( files ).mapToLong( File::length ).sum();
```

Where `toStream` is my static utility function to convert an Iterable to a Stream. Just this:

```
StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
```

Comment: `fileTreeTraverser`is now deprecated

Comment: @Drakes `Files.fileTraverser().breadthFirst()` or `MoreFiles.fileTraverser(sourcePath).breadthFirst()`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can't.

The exception is coming from `FileTreeWalker.visit`.

To be precise, it is trying to build a `newDirectoryStream` when it fails (this code is out of your control):

```
// file is a directory, attempt to open it
DirectoryStream<Path> stream = null;
try {
    stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(entry);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    return new Event(EventType.ENTRY, entry, ioe); // ==> Culprit <== 
} catch (SecurityException se) {
    if (ignoreSecurityException)
        return null;
    throw se;
}
```

Maybe you should [submit a bug](http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/index.jsp).

Comment: I've submitted one descries my exact case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220542

Answer (score 1):

filter out directories -> Files::isRegularFile

```
try(Stream<Path> pathStream = Files.walk(Path.of("/path/to/your/dir"))
        ) {
            pathStream
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```