# Files.walk how to swallow the exception and continue walking in the filesystem

Tags: java, nio, java-8, java-stream

I am try using the following code:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("/home"), FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
    .map(p -> p.getFileName())
    .map(f -> f.toString())
    .filter(s -> s.endsWith(".rb"))
    .forEach(o -> System.out.println(o));
```

When I run it as a regular user, I got AccessDeniedException Wrapped in UncheckIOException..And when Run as root, I got the correct result.

```
$ java helloJava8.LambdaExpr 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/lost+found
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:88)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(FileTreeIterator.java:104)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
    at .......
$sudo java helloJava8.LambdaExpr 
hello.rb
```

I **do know** the cause of the problem, but what I want to know how to swallow this exception, because if i wrap the above code in `Try-Catch` block, I got the method `walk` finish its work and stop walk-though the fs.

Comment: on your `p` map lambda, try checking if you have permissions/access to the file first

Comment: I've submitted a bug for this. When I've a bug number, I gonna put it here ..

Comment: The bug (enhancement request) for this is [JDK-8039910](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039910). And yes, this question is a duplicate.