# What is the most effective way to read names of a lot of files?

Tags: java, file

I need to get names of a lot of folders and files in the folders. I tried using `FileUtils`, but it's too slow compared to java's native `Files.walk()`, and I can't use it because of that reason.

But I can't even use the java's `Files.walk()` because when it tries to read a hidden file, it throws `Exception` and stops (the hidden file cannot be avoided, someone said it's a design mistake - [Files.walk skip directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644979/files-walk-skip-directories)). Is there any different way? I don't know what to do now.

Comment: [`FileVisitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Files.walk(), calculate total size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867286/files-walk-calculate-total-size) It doesn't do exactly what you want it to do, but the answer from 2017 explains how to use the FileWalkTree and FileVisitor pattern to do this fast.

Comment: Or [Catch UncheckedIOException in Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558339/catch-uncheckedioexception-in-java-8-stream)?

Comment: I tried FileVisitor but it's still too slow. Is it just a limitation of the language? Or is there a faster way to read file names?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do the following in your code.-

```
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.HiddenFileFilter;
```

I will give you an example-

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.HiddenFileFilter;

public class ListHiddenAndVisibleFilesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File directory = new File(".");

        System.out.println("Hidden Files:");
        File[] hiddenFiles = directory.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.HIDDEN);
        for (File hiddenFile : hiddenFiles) {
            System.out.println("hidden file: " + hiddenFile.getCanonicalPath());
        }

        System.out.println("\nVisible Files:");
        File[] visibleFiles = directory.listFiles((FileFilter) HiddenFileFilter.VISIBLE);
        for (File visibleFile : visibleFiles) {
            System.out.println("visible file: " + visibleFile.getCanonicalPath());
        }
    }
}
```

This gives result like

```
Hidden Files:
hidden file: C:\kum\workspace\test\hidden1.txt
hidden file: C:\kum\workspace\test\hidden2.txt

Visible Files:
visible file: C:\kum\workspace\test\.classpath
visible file: C:\kum\workspace\test\.project
visible file: C:\kum\workspace\test\visibleFile.txt
```