# Files.walk skip directories

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to write a program the list files recursively in my external hd but there is this recycle bin folder that I don't have access to.  I want to skip the folder but can't seem to do it.

Is there anything wrong with this code below?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String path = "K:\\";

    Files.walk(Paths.get(path))
            .filter(it -> !it.toString().startsWith("K:\\$RECYCLE.BIN"))
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

It keeps giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: K:\$RECYCLE.BIN\S-1-5-21-684815243-3314879918-332412784-1001
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:88)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(FileTreeIterator.java:104)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it's a design issue with `Files.walk`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22868706/3284624) for details.

Comment: oh ok so I guess I have to do it the old fashion way of recursive functions?

Comment: No, not necessarily. There are several ways you could walk the file tree. For example you could use `FileVisitor` as [described here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html)