# list fixed no of files from directory in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a workaround for Java's poor performance on walking huge directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354703/is-there-a-workaround-for-javas-poor-performance-on-walking-huge-directories)

I created a utility which lists all the files within some directory by using **File.listFiles()** function, but the problem occurred when i copied huge amount of files (around 100K) under that directory.

I was looking for some solution take actually takes some fixed no of files (say X) from that directory and processes and then deletes those files and takes next X number of files. 
Can any one please suggest me any solution.

Regards

Comment: I think Pauls suggestion below is more elegant than the above link, but that is just my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to use a `FileNameFilter` that either returns `false` after a certain number of files have been accepted or, if you are prepared to abuse Exceptions a little, throw an `Exception` at that point.

```
class CountedFilter implements FilenameFilter {
  int limit = 0;

  public CountedFilter ( int limit ) {
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  public boolean accept(File file, String string) {
    return limit-- > 0;
  }

}
```

---

There is another option which is nowhere near as succinct but I believe is more effective. It involves a `FilenameFilter` that posts each file back to the caller through a `BlockingQueue`. The `File.list` is called in a separate thread so you don't have to wait for it to complete.

This solution has the added benefit that the files can be processed while `File.list` is running producing a much smoother solution, much like an iterator. If encouraged I will post the code as a separate answer.

Comment: i am not sure but i see no benefit using FileNameFilter  ..actually the files types in the directory are of same type and filenames are random based on datetime, so how can i use this FileNameFilter..

Comment: that looks promising, let me try this. thanks for now.

Comment: Note that this will not deliver the files in any predictable order. To select just the oldest files you will have to list all of them.

Comment: i think it won't be any issue as i am not concerned with the sequence and my function deletes that file after execution